# Passing an array to a function as array vs as a pointer

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers, parameters

I am a newbie to C and I am looking the ways to pass an array to a function and access the elements.

I find that there are 3 ways to do that.

1. pass in an array, and the function specific the parameters as type of **array**
2. pass in an array, and the function specific the parameters as type of **pointer**
3. pass in the address of the first element (actually this address is equal to the array address, i think this is the same as the method 2)

What I don't understand is that, using the method 1. The address of the array passing in is different from the address of the array parameter in the function. What is the difference of using the method 1 and method 2.

code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void pass_by_array(int x[]);
void pass_by_pointer(int *x);
int main(void){
    int i;
    int base[5] = {3, 7, 2, 4, 5};
    printf("address of first element in main %p\n", &base[0]);
    printf("address of array in main %p \n\n", &base);
    pass_by_array(base);
    pass_by_pointer(base);
}

/* Pass in the array as type of int x [] */
void pass_by_array(int x[]){
    printf("address of first element passed in: %p \n", &x[0]);
    printf("address of array passed in: %p \n\n", &x);
}

/* Pass in the array as type of int pointer*/
void pass_by_pointer(int *x){
    printf("passing in array by pointer, address: %p",x);
}
```

output:

```
address of first element in main 0xbfcea3ac
address of array in main 0xbfcea3ac 

address of first element passed in: 0xbfcea3ac 
address of array passed in: 0xbfcea390 

passing in array by pointer, address: 0xbfcea3ac%
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

```
printf("address of array passed in: %p \n\n", &x);
```

Is wrong.  You are not printing out the address of the array, but the address of the local variable that the array pointer is stored in.  (Yes, `x` is actually a pointer.)  Just print out `x`:

```
printf("address of array passed in: %p \n\n", x);
```

The answer is that in this case it doesn't matter much which way you declare it.  `int[]` and `int*` in C are sometimes interchangeable, and this is one of the cases where they are.

Further reading:

- [Are pointers and arrays equivalent in C?](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2009/10/21/are-pointers-and-arrays-equivalent-in-c/)  (Specifically, see the "arrays passed to functions are converted to pointers" section.)

Comment: thanks for your quick response. Oh! Sorry for what a stupid mistake I have made. I will accept your answer as quick as possible :)

Comment: @code4j I would not call it a stupid mistake. C is a complex language with very specific and situational rules. Everybody runs into this question sooner or later.

Answer (score 2):

Though they have the same compiler semantics, there is a good reason for using using the `[]` form at times. Specifically when you expect the argument to *represent an array of a particular dimension* (either static or or specified in another passed argument), you can make you intention clearer than using the `*` syntax.

That is

```
int arraySum(int n, int ary[n]);
```

documents the meaning of the argument `n`, while

```
int arraySum(int n, int *ary);
```

does not.

Similarly

```
void crossProduct(double result[3], double v1[3], double v2[3]);
```

makes it clear that the arguments are expected to be 3-dimensional vectors while

```
void crossProduct(double *result, double *v1, double *v2);
```

leaves the reader guessing.

Again, the compiler treats these as the same, but a human reader can get more information out of one form than the other.

Comment: I'm normally in favor of self-documenting code, but I personally would prefer describing the expected array size in a comment rather than using `double result[3]`.  I think the latter is misleading since the compiler won't check it at all.

Comment: @jamesdlin This is not exclusive of proper documentation, but in addition to. And yeah, the compiler not checking is awkward.

Comment: True, it's not exclusive of proper documentation, but I feel it's awkward enough that it warrants *additional* documentation (e.g. `double result[3], // The compiler doesn't enforce the array size, and don't use sizeof on this`), and that point, I feel it's not worth the effort.

Comment: @jamesdlin c is full of things that are the programmer's job to ensure and that the compiler doesn't check or enforce. As I see it, this is about communicating with the next programmer down the pipe.